# JPOS Parsing repetitive tags under same field and dataset

Tags: java, apache-camel, iso8583, jpos

I am new to JPOS and trying to parse field ISO 8083 field 55 Dataset 05 TAG 80. We are using the org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg to parse the fields.The tag 80 as shown below can be repeated twice with different values 05 and 06. ISOMsg that we use use assigns field into a Treemap and hence the repetitive tag which is 80 seems to ignored. please help on this.

F56  Customer Related Data          0068
**56.1  DSI - Account Owner Data     05**
56.2  Dataset Length               0051
**56.3  Account Reference Code       8002 06**
56.4  Account Owner City Name      8B07 Chennai
56.5  Account Owner Country        8E03 CAN
56.6  Account Owner Postal Code    8A06 956789
56.7  Account Owner Address Line 1 860C addressLine1
56.8  Account Owner Address Line 2 870C addressLine2
56.9  Account Owner Street Name    880C addressLine3
56.10 Account Owner Name - Given   8304 John
56.11 Account Owner Name - Last    8505 Smith
56.12 DSI - Account Owner Data     05
56.13 Dataset Length               0011
**56.14 Account Reference Code       8002 05**
56.15 Account Owner Name - Given   8304 Jane
56.16 Account Owner Name - Last    8505 Smith

How do we get parse both the tag 80 fields in the same dataset using JPOS

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `org.jpos.tlv` package?